# how to join table only not rows

Tags: mysql, sql, select, join

I wanted to join the table data just without increasing the no. of rows.
and **the 2 tables are joining without primary key ,only with the help of a column which is common in both ,no other column i can use for result because no other is related at all.**
**Table 1**

```
  id1(pk)   name   country  clm_id
   1    abc     3        23
   2    abc     4        23
```

**table 2**

```
   id2(pk)   city    state    clm_id
    1    cdv      5        23
    2    sdc      5        23
```

i want **to join these table by clm_id** but it is giving me 4 rows,
**i want**

```
      id1   name   country  clm_id  id2   city    state  
        1    abc     3        23     1    cdv      5  
        2    abc     4        23     2    sdc      5
```

**but i'm getting**

```
      id1   name   country  clm_id  id2   city    state  
        1    abc     3        23     1    cdv      5  
        1    abc     3        23     2    sdc      5  
        2    abc     4        23     1    cdv      5 
        2    abc     4        23     2    sdc      5
```

how to do this..
        please look at this link..  [example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6418c/1)

Comment: What query are you using? Probably missing the join's `ON` clause.

Comment: i'm using "join" with "on" itself but i'm getting 4 rows...:(

Comment: If you edit your question and include your query, in general we can help you much more easily :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Probably you are joining like this one below, which produces cartesian product.

```
SELECT  a.*, b.*
FROM    table1 a,table2 b
```

This should be pretty straight forward.

```
SELECT  a.*, b.*
FROM    table1 a
        INNER JOIN table2 b
            ON a.id1 = b.id2
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo Link](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3c8a0/1)

To learn more aboud joins, see the link below.

- [Visual Representation of SQL Joins](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/33052/Visual-Representation-of-SQL-Joins)

**UPDATE 1**

```
SELECT  b.FLD_CUSTOMER_CLAIM_ID, 
        FLD_CUSTOMER_REG_CONTACT_ID,    
        FLD_TYPE,   
        FLD_NAME,   
        FLD_EMAIL_ID,   
        FLD_MOBILE, 
        FLD_DEPARTMENT, 
        FLD_ROLE,   
        FLD_SALUTATION,
        FLD_CRM_CUSTOMER_REG_TAX_ID,    
        FLD_TAX_TYPE,   
        FLD_APPLICABLE_FLAG,    
        FLD_MANUAL_FILLING_FLAG,    
        FLD_EFILLING_FLAG
FROM
  (
    SELECT @row:=@row+1 RowNo, a.*
    FROM   TBL_CUSTOMER_REGISTRATION_CONTACT_DETAILS a, (SELECT @row:=0) s
    WHERE  a.FLD_CUSTOMER_CLAIM_ID = 32768
  ) b INNER JOIN
  (
    SELECT @rowB:=@rowB+1 RowNo, a.*
    FROM   TBL_CUSTOMER_REGISTRATION_TAX_DETAILS a, (SELECT @rowB:=0) s
    WHERE  a.FLD_CUSTOMER_CLAIM_ID = 32768
  ) c ON b.RowNo = c.RowNo
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo Link](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6418c/22)

Comment: join not giving me answer...

Comment: what do you mean it doesn't give you the answer? please click the link to see the demonstration.

Comment: i gave one link please look at that..

Comment: yep i saw that, you are joining via `FLD_CUSTOMER_CLAIM_ID` (*value of `32768`*) which has two rows for each table, thus giving you 4 records. what is your desired result then?

Comment: yes i know you want two rows but what exactly are those? the query is correct and gives proper result but unfortunately it's not the one you are expecting. I need the values of the rows you want to be returned.

Comment: i want 2 rows with claim_id = 32768 having all the data which is in the 2 tables. means only i want to join the table1 columns with columns of other table..without feeding any extra rows

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/21976/discussion-between-jw-and-sourcecode)